# if statement based on two variables matching a row in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a little trouble thinking of how to write the condition for the if statement of the following. So I have a database with two columns: ID and Username.   I would like to write an if else statement that compares both variables $ID and $Username with the rows of the database.  If it matches I want the statement to die and if it doesn't match i want to }else{ some other code.  So I am thinking it would be something like this:

```
$ID = 5;
$Username = 'Butterdog';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM database");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{  
 if  $ID and $Username both match any row in the database { die
 }else{ do some other code }};
```

So I am just having trouble thinking of how to write the condition that compares BOTH variables to each  row in the database.  I know this must be elementary but I just haven't come across it yet and my searching has come up null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot easier (and more efficient) to do the actual comparison in the query.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT TRUE AS row
    FROM db WHERE id = ? AND user = ? LIMIT 1");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $ID, $Username);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $found);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if ($found) {
    exit;
}
else { /* do something else */ }
```

Comment: yes, that does seem the better way to go with it.  Thanks.  I write it up and come back with the good news that it all works in a few minutes hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming your database column names are id and username

```
if  ($ID == $row['id'] && $Username == $row['username'] {
    die;
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: So I can just throw a AND in the if statement?  I did not know that (obviously, lol)   Thanks.  I will give that a try.

Comment: You were right, AND and && work the same.  && is the preferred method it would seem though.  Thanks acutesoftware.

Answer (score 1):

```
if  ($ID == $row['id'] && $Username === $row['username'] {
    die("found row");
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Be careful when comparing strings because == gives unexpected results, sometimes even with strings. 'a string' == 0 also evaluates to true because any string is converted into an integer when compared with an integer. If PHP can't properly convert the string then it is evaluated as 0. So 0 is equal to 0, which equates as true. This is just one example. 
Another advice would be to be careful with your naming style in php, to be consistent with other developers try using camelcase or underscore and don't start your variables with an uppercase.
And the last advice would be to be careful with the mysql column names too, because they are case sensitive only on linux, on windows they are case insensitive. So try naming with lowercase letters and use underscores.